# Get fixed children

Tags: javascript, treenode

I have such HTML:

```
<div class = "touch" onclick="do(this)">
  <span>text01</span>
  <span>text02</span>
  <span>text03</span>
  <span>text04</span>
  <div class = "findMe">andHideMe</div>
</div>
<div class = "touch" onclick="do(this)">
  <span>text01</span>
  <span>text02</span>
  <div class = "findMe">andHideMe</div>
</div>
<div class = "touch" onclick="do(this)">
  <span></span>
  <span>just</span>
  <div class = "findMe">andHideMe</div>
</div>
```

When I click on TOUCH, DIV 'FindMe' can do smth.

How can I choose 'FindMe' in TOUCH using THIS
using JavaScript
???

```
function do(obj)
{
    var se = obj.childNodes;
    for (var t = 0; t < obj.childNodes.length; t++)
    {
        if (se[t].className == 'findMe')
        {
            se[t].className.style.display = 'none';
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: use jquery, becomes very easy: `this.find('.findMe').hide();`

Comment: $(obj).siblings('.findMe').hide();

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
se[t].className.style.display = 'none';
```

to

```
se[t].style.display = 'none';
```

You may wish to include a simple  *hasClass* function like:

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
    return re.test(element.className);
}

// or

function hasClass(element, className) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') > -1;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
if (hasClass(se[t], className)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery find div Class.

var findMeDivClass = $('.findMe');

and id find : var findMeDivId = $('#findMe');

and attr find : var findMeDivAttr = $('[name="findMe"]');